# wait() does not force the thread to wait?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I have two threads t0 and t1 with runnables posted below in the code section Run_0 and Run1 respectively. what I want to do is, when t0 is writing or doing its task that lasts for 7 seconds, t1 should be waiting. and when the 
7 seconds elapse, t1 should be notified to continue working. I tried to do that using wait() and notify() but at run time i expected t0 to start but the console displays only "T1 is working" and t0 prints nothing as if it was not
started

please let me know why such behaviour is happening.

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    t0 = new Thread(new Run_0());
    t1 = new Thread(new Run_1());

    t0.start();
    t1.start();
}

private static class Run_0 implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while (true) {
            long startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();
            synchronized (t1) {
                try {
                    t1.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("T0 is writing");
            //simulate doing some work
            while( (TimeUtils.getTSSec()-startTime) <= 7) {

            }
            System.out.println("T0 finished writing");

            synchronized (t1) {
                t1.notify();
            }

            startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();

            while( (TimeUtils.getTSSec()-startTime) <= 7) {

            }
        }

    }

}

private static class Run_1 implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("T1 is working");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look on how to use `wait` and `notify` here first: http://www.qat.com/using-waitnotify-instead-thread-sleep-java/

Comment: Or here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) (emphasis mine):

> Causes the **current thread** to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object.

Your code causes `t0` to wait, not `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

`wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll` should be inside `synchronized` block. You have one `notify` that is outside it:

```
        t1.notify(); // <-------
        startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();
```

Comment: ok i corrected the code and now t1.notify in inside the synchronized block,,but i still get the same results

Comment: While your statement is correct, it does nothing to address the question.

Comment: @bradimus Question before edit was citing the exception that was happening, now it was removed, not sure why (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38612670/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

> the console displays only "T1 is working" and t0 prints nothing as if it was not started

Right because the first thing in `Run_0.run()` is `t1.wait();`.  That is waiting for someone to call `t1.notify()` or `t1.notifyAll()`.  I see no one calling those.

When a thread calls `wait()` on an object, it causes the thread to wait for the monitor on the object to be notified.  One thread doesn't cause another thread to wait.  It can only wait itself.

It is important to realize that you are synchronizing, waiting, and notifying on the `t1` object which happens to be a thread.  Any object shared between the two threads will work and since we are getting confused with locking on the `t0` or `t1` thread object, you should instead create a final lock object and lock on it:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

> t0 is writing or doing its task that lasts for 7 seconds, t1 should be waiting.

So it sounds like you should have the `t1.wait()` in the `Run_1` class not the `Run_0` class.  Maybe `Run_0` should do:

```
// much better way to simulate time passing instead of a spin loop
Thread.sleep(7000);
System.out.println("T0 finished writing");
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notify();
}
```

and then in `Run_1` you'd do something like:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.wait();
}
System.out.println("T1 is working");
```

Notice that I'm using the common `lock` object.

Comment: i think Run_1 should contain: synchronized (t0) {
      try {
       t0.wait();
      }

Comment: It doesn't matter what object you user @user2121.  You just need to use the same object in both threads.  I'll change my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer @user2121 which tries to explain that using the thread objects is confusing your understanding of `object.wait()` and `object.notify()`.  Hope it helps.